# Powershell New-Item command returns 'The path is not of a legal form'

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble with a script that fails at the New-Item point

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path \\hv02\VMShare\sdn-NC02
```

The VMShare is created remotely via invoke-command

```
New-SmbShare -Name VMShare -Path C:\ClusterStorage\Vol1-1\VMs -FullAccess DOMAIN\administrator -Temporary
```

Error is always

```
New-Item : The path is not of a legal form.
```

Google is not very helpful (searches result in C# errors)

Does anyone have any idea about what the actual error could be?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the FQDN name for the share path?

Comment: Have tried with \\server\share\folder, and \\fqdn\share\folder
The command is typed correctly as it works in creating a local folder, and using the command the same way, but in a different environment.
The user executing the command is a domain admin, and both computers are in the same domain

Comment: What is current location when script execute `New-Item` cmdlet?

Comment: You gave Domain\administrator Full Access to the newly created share. Is that the credential that the script is running under? You say the user executing the command is "a domain admin", but that isn't the same as the "Domain\administrator" user.

Comment: Using DOMAIN\Administrator to run the script, and giving that user full access in the same command that creates the share (second code line above)
That's what's so puzzling. There is no way that can't work.
I wanted a fresh pair of eyes on this.